# Filter two users for Row Level Security

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database, row-level-security

I'm going to use Row Level Security in Sql server Management Studio

I need help with how I can assign 2 users where one user can see their own rows which has "purple" in rows, and the other user which will be the  Manager, is going to have access to see rows that contains "Purple" and "Black" data.

### **For example:**

```
Execute as user = 'User1'
select * 
from colours
```

The User1 will see only rows that contains "Purple"

---

```
Execute as user = 'Manager'
select *
from colours
```

The Manager will see all the User1 rows (Purple data) and their own row (Black data)

Comment: What in particular are you having difficulty with? Have you created a security function yet? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how I can define which roles/users can see what.

Here is my script:

RETURN SELECT 1 AS fn_securitypredicate_result 
Where @columnname = USER_NAME() OR USER_NAME() = 'Manager'
I have not defined "User1" here. How can the database know that User1 can only see their rows which contains "Purple"?

Comment: Can you update your question with the predicate function and the security policy codes you have tried so far?

Comment: Does your function have an input parameter to accept the colour? Please post your full function so we can help rather than taking guesses